# Map a dto to an entity retrieved from database if Dto has Id using MapStruct

Tags: java, mapping, data-transfer-objects, mapstruct

I'm using **MapStruct** to make `dto <-> entity` mapping. The same mappers are used to *create* **and** *update* entities from dtos. A verification of the dto's id is done to know whether a new entity must be created (id == null) or it should be retrieved from database (id != null) .

I'm actually using [MapperDecorator](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators) as a workaround. Example :

### Mapper

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(UserAccountDecorator.class)
public interface UserAccountMapper {

    UserAccountDto map(User user);

    User map(UserAccountDto dto);

    User map(UserAccountDto dto, @MappingTarget User user);
}
```

### Decorator

```
public abstract class UserAccountDecorator implements UserAccountMapper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private UserAccountMapper delegate;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User map(UserAccountDto dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        }

        User user = new User();
        if (dto.getId() != null) {
            user = userRepository.findOne(dto.getId());
        }

        return delegate.map(dto, user);
    }

}
```

But this solution becomes heavy due to the fact that a decorator must be created for each mapper.

Is there any good solution to perform that ?

---

I'm using :

1. MapStruct : **1.1.0**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved my problem by following the advice of [Gunnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773616/gunnar) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367081/map-a-dto-to-an-entity-retrieved-from-database-if-dto-has-id-using-mapstruct/42375045#42375045).

I moved to [MapStruct 1.2.0.Beta1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mapstruct%7Cmapstruct-jdk8%7C1.2.0.Beta1%7Cjar) and created a UserMapperResolver like below

```
@Component
public class UserMapperResolver {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @ObjectFactory
    public User resolve(BaseUserDto dto, @TargetType Class<User> type) {
        return dto != null && dto.getId() != null ? userRepository.findOne(dto.getId()) : new User();
    }

}
```

Which I use then in my UserMapper :

```
@Mapper(uses = { UserMapperResolver.class })
public interface BaseUserMapper {

    BaseUserDto map(User user);

    User map(BaseUserDto baseUser);

}
```

The generated code is now :

```
@Override
    public User map(BaseUserDto baseUser) {
        if ( baseUser == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        User user = userMapperResolver.resolve( baseUser, User.class );

        user.setId( baseUser.getId() );
        user.setSocialMediaProvider( baseUser.getSocialMediaProvider() );
...
}
```

Works well !

Comment: Hi Radouane ROUFID, thanks for sharing your final solution. I have a small question : Let's admit I want to affect in my resolver, an object retrieved from my Repository into a field of the entity Object. It is possible to do this in Object Factories of MapStruct ? Didn't found any similar use case examples.

EG: I have a User which have a Phone entity in OneToOne relationship. If I get a UserDto which contains a phoneId and I want to map it to a User with an actual Phone entity. thanks !

Comment: You can inject you PhoneRepository in your UserResolver and fetch the phone entity from db. 

`@Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
    private PhoneREpository phoneRe;

    @ObjectFactory
    public User resolve(BaseUserDto dto, @TargetType Class<User> type) {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(dto.getId());
user.setPhone(phoneRep.getFIndOne(dto.getPhoneId()))
return user;
    }`

Comment: Yes I would do that but in the case of the creation of a User ? I return a new User item with just the Phone info but nothing else ? Does mapper is called after to complete the object with the actual DTO or do we have to do all the mapping logic in the resolver ?

Comment: ObjectFactory create/fetch the object in which the mapping will be done. You can check the generated code in my solution.

Comment: awsome solution like it so much

Answer (score 2):

MapStruct alone can't do that. However, with some generics and a main abstract class you can make your life easier.

You need one generic interface. It must not be annotated with `@Mapper`, because if it is MapStruct will try to generate an implementation and it will fail. It cannot generate generic mappers.

```
public interface GenericMapper<E, DTO> {

    DTO map(E entity);

    E map(DTO dto);

    E map(DTO dto, @MappingTarget E entity);
}
```

Then you need one `abstract` class where you'll have your logic.

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericMapper<E, DTO> implements GenericMapper<E, DTO> {

    @Autowired
    private Repository<E> repository;

    @Override
    public final E map (DTO dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // You can also use a Java 8 Supplier and pass it down the constructor
        E entity = newInstance();
        if (dto.getId() != null) {
            user = repository.findOne(dto.getId());
        }

        return map(dto, entity);
    }

    protected abstract E newInstance();
}
```

And then each of your mappers will only need to extend this `abstract` class.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class UserAccountMapper extends AbstractGenericMapper<User, UserDto> {

    protected User newInstance() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

MapStruct will then generate an implementation for your mapper and you will only have to extend the `AbstractGenericMapper` for the future. Of course you will need to adapt the generic parameters so you can at least get the id from the via some interface maybe. If you have different type of ids then you will have to add that generic parameter to the `AbstractGenericMapper` as well.

Comment: Thank you Filip, I will try this solution !

Comment: An alternative may be object factory methods receiving the source objects as enabled in [MapStruct 1.2.0.Beta1](http://mapstruct.org/news/2017-02-20-mapstruct-1_2_0_Beta1-is-out-with-lombok-support-and-direct-field-access/#more-powerful-target-bean-factories) (released yesterday). You could have a generic factory method which either instantiates a new entity or loads it from the database, depending on the DTO state (id present or not).

Comment: Very nice, This solution is better. Thank you Gunnar, You are doing a great job !

Comment: I was also thinking about the new possibility of the factory methods to return an object. However,  if that is used,  MapStruct will immediately return the object if isn't `null`